# How MySQL's 'UNION' remove duplicates with multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

I know the main difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` is the former removes duplicated records, while the latter keeps all. My question is on how `UNION` removes duplicated record if there are multiple columns? For example, to union `T1(A, B, C)` and `T2(A, B, C)`,

1. will MySQL consider `(a1, b1, c1)` and `(a1, b2, c2)` duplicates?
2. if there were duplicates in T1 itself, will MySQL remove this kind of duplicates?

Comment: A duplicate row is one in which ALL columns are equal. So (a1, b1, c1) is not a duplicate of (a1, b2, c2). But if you had two rows (a1, b1, c1) in T1 or in T2 or one of the rows was in T1 and the other in T2 then your result set would only have one (a1, b1, c1) row in it.

Comment: Just think of both results being appended together and then a distinct being run.  Doesn't matter which table has duplicates... all are removed.

Answer (score 1):

During a `UNION` (not a `UNION ALL`) query, MySQL first combines the records from all the tables involved, and then removes all duplicates.

Consider taking the `UNION` of the following two tables:

```
table1
col1 | col2
1    | 1
1    | 1
2    | 2
2    | 2
3    | 4

table2
col1 | col2
1    | 1
1    | 1
3    | 4
```

Consider the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
```

The output would be this:

```
col1 | col2
1    | 1
2    | 2
3    | 4
```

In other words, simply because `(1, 1)` was duplicated within each separate table does not mean that it appears in duplicate in the result set.  This output is only consistent with MySQL first combining all records and then removing duplicates.  This has the side effect that if a record appear in duplicate within one of the tables, it also gets removed.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester